# How do you update a listview in a flutter android home screen widget?

Tags: android, flutter, android-widget

I'm doing the typical todo list project to learn flutter and wanted to have a go at making a home screen widget for android.

I've not done much work on android but I don't see a way to update a listview in the widget? It seems straightforward enough if I just want to update a text box, but more complicated layouts seem unsupported.

Is this the case or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListView.builder()` to prepare the `ListView` and just return any `customWidget` from `itemBuilder`.

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 10,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(),
);
```

Comment: This is flutter code isn't it? I'm specifically talking about home screen widgets, which I don't believe can be done in flutter directly?